# C# How do you add a ListView ClickListener

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, listview, xamarin

I want to add a ListView ClickListener to a ListView, but I don't know how?
Here is the end of my code where I Create an Adapter:

```
//Get all the values from Name, and convert it to an Array
        string[] NamesArray = coins.Select(c => c.Name).ToArray();

        //Fill the DataSource of the ListView with the Array of Names
        ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, NamesArray);

        //Bind DataSource to ListView
        ListviewCoinNames.Adapter = adapter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a ItemClick handler

```
ListviewCoinNames.ItemClick += ListviewCoinNames_ItemClick;
```

then define it

```
    void ListviewCoinNames_ItemClick(Object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mItems[e.Position]);
    }
```

Comment: Define it outside the: "protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)"?

Comment: Yes, but in your example is my mItems an Array, converted from a List.

Comment: So, do I need to change mItems to the Array, or the List name? My Adapter is filled by the Array!

Comment: It doesn’t matter.  e.Position gives you the index of the element that was clicked.  Use that index to reference the item in whatever your data source is

Answer (score 0):

You can do as says @Jason or in [Design], select ListView, then in Properties-->Events and double click on the event you want, this automatically generates the methods

[image]